# Meteor - change helper collection sort order after rendering

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Inside Meteor, I wish to change the order of a collection that is rendered inside a loop dynamically:

```
Template.chartPage.helpers({

    employee:function(){

        sortArr = [];
    var timePeriod = Session.get("period");
    var currentPage = Session.get("current_page");
        sortArr[currentPage+'.'+timePeriod] = "asc";
        return EmployeeCollection.find({}, sortArr).fetch();
    },
});
```

HTML:

```
{{#each employee}}
    {{first_name}}
{{/each}}
```

I want it so that when the session variable for `period` and `current_page` change, so does the sort order in the helper - the session variables do get updated, but the template isn't rerendered into a sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In meteor the database is (at the moment) based off mongodb. Ascending is `1` and Descending is `-1`. Your final array must be something like:

```
return EmployeeCollection.find({}, {sort : {number: -1, size: 1} })
```

Should get you the following order (each line is a document) with a `number` and `size` field.

```
{ number : 5, size: 1, _id: ...}
{ number : 4, size: 2, _id: ...}
{ number : 3, size: 3, _id: ...}
```

More details on how to order with mongodb at : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

On another note you dont have to use `fetch()` when returning a cursor to a template helper. Meteor will automatically parse through it without having to go through it as an array (with fetch)

You can build the sort query using `Session` as you are as long as you follow this structure. As soon as you change the `Session` hash the order will be automatically changed and re-rendered.